# Not being able to set cookie expiry date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Below is the code to set cookies with its expiry. The two cookie values 'someToken' and 'wofilter' are set for the browser but the date of expiry is different in both the cases.(case 2  is set to session which i have problem with)

I would like to set the cookie with expiry for two days. One difference I have found is that case one uses simple string while the other uses stringified object.

Can somebody explain why they behave differently

**1. Case one**

```
exp = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate())
console.log exp
$cookies.put 'someToken', 'blabla', expires: exp
```

**2. Case two**

```
expireDate = new Date()
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1)

$cookies.put 'woFilter' + $routeParams.id,  JSON.stringify testObj, expires: exp
```

Thanks in advance :)

I am attaching an image which show the browser cookie details

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this and call it by your parameters.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```